# How to use django-iban in my own django models form?

Tags: django

How to import IbanAccountField to my model?

https://github.com/benkonrath/django-iban

models.py

```
class Money(models.Model):
    number = models.IbanAccountField(max_length=50)
```

forms.py

```
class MoneyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Money
```

My error: **AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'IbanAccountField'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from django_iban.fields import IbanAccountField`

```
class Money(models.Model):
    number = IbanAccountField(max_length=50)
```

Comment: Thanks but: ImportError: cannot import name IbanAccountField My traceback: http://wklej.org/id/924837/

Answer (score 1):

The field named changed in django_iban >= 0.2.0 so you now have to do something like this:

```
from django_iban.fields import IBANField

class Customer(models.Model):
    iban = IBANField()
```

Note: You do not need to specify `max_length=50` because an IBAN has only up to 34 characters and the field already takes care of that. See the wikipedia page for more information:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022, django-iban is [deprecated](https://pypi.org/project/django-iban/) and you should use django-localflavor instead [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/django-localflavor/), [readthedocs.io](https://django-localflavor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generic/), [github.com](https://github.com/django/django-localflavor).